# How do I make my controls inside a UserControl private?

Tags: wpf, user-controls, access-modifiers

I have a user control with a ComboBox and a TextBox.  Everything is working great except I noticed that from my user control's instance object, I can access those two controls.  They shouldn't be accessible except via my own exposed properties.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use the [x:FieldModifier attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970905.aspx) on your controls, thusly:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox1" x:FieldModifier="private" />
```

Interestingly the MSDN page for x:FieldModifier doesn't give "private" as a valid value for the attribute, but I've tested it and it works.