# How do I make my controls inside a winforms UserControl private?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, user-controls

I would like to make the controls inside my user control private, so that only the methods/properties I choose to expose are accessible.

I found this similar question: [How do I make my controls inside a UserControl private?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300255/how-do-i-make-my-controls-inside-a-usercontrol-private)

However, I would like to know how/if this can be done in windows forms (not wpf.)

It seems like something that should be really simple... what am I missing?

Thanks.

EDIT: In response to some of the comments/answers, I just want to make it clear that I am using VB.net for which the default modifier for a control is "friend", not "Private".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the modifier of the control to private  notice that this is private by default in winforms c# but in vb win forms this will be set to friend by default.

[image]

Comment: @TimonPost Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend changing the Modifiers, as per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233630(v=vs.110).aspx .